# SQL error: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to use the query below as a sub-query in another statement, but the moment I enclose it in parenthesis, I get the error "missing right parenthesis".

Without the braces, it's executing fine.

What is the problem here? I need to enclose the statement within braces to use it as a sub-query with another statement. What do i do?

```
(SELECT dname 
 FROM   student, 
        major 
 WHERE  student.sid = major.sid 
        AND year = 5 
 GROUP  BY year, 
          dname 
 HAVING Count(student.sid) > 5 
 ORDER  BY year)
```

Comment: Post with your main query

Comment: Removed `mysql` tag as the query clearly can't be used there (because of the CTE)

Comment: @anvitapotluri You should add the main query that you placed in the comments into your question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `ORDER BY` with a subquery inside `IN`. Because literally `IN` doesn't care about the order in which you specify the values

```
 with temp as (select dname, count(sid) as majors
 from major 
 group by dname
 order by majors desc)
 select dname
 from temp
 where majors > 15 or dname in  (SELECT dname 
  FROM   student, 
        major 
  WHERE  student.sid = major.sid 
        AND year = 5 
  GROUP  BY year, 
          dname 
  HAVING Count(student.sid) > 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 with   major as (
 select major.dname,major.sid from ( 
                 values ('d1',101), ('d1',102),
                  ('d1',103), ('d2',201), ('d2',202), ('d2',203)
                 ) as major(dname,sid)
),
student as 
(select sid,year from (
values (101,5),(102,5),(103,4),(104,3),(105,2),(106,1),(107,4)
) as student(sid,year)
),
temp as (   
   select major.dname, count(major.sid) as majors
 from     ( 
                 values ('d1',101), ('d1',102),
                  ('d1',103), ('d2',201), ('d2',202), ('d2',203)
                 ) as major(dname,sid)
 group by dname
 --order by majors desc
 --The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
 )
 select dname
 from temp
 where majors > 2 or dname in  (SELECT dname 
  FROM   student, 
        major 
  WHERE  student.sid = major.sid 
        AND year = 5 
  GROUP  BY year, 
          dname 
  HAVING Count(student.sid) > 5 )
```

**Output**

```
dname
d1
d2
```